# Difference between assigning object to variable and passing it as argument VS directly creating object and passing it in argument

Tags: c#, oop

What is the difference in both and which is recommended and why?

```
        var getDetailsReq = new getTransactionDetailsRequest
        {
            transId = transactionResponse.Payload.Id
        };
        var getDetailsCont = new getTransactionDetailsController(getDetailsReq);
```

vs

```
        var getDetailsCont = new getTransactionDetailsController(new getTransactionDetailsRequest
        {
            transId = transactionResponse.Payload.Id
        });
```

The first one holds the address of the object in the memory and it will clean out when dispose off

The second one will go untraceable and will be lost somewhere in memory

makes sense or do you have something to correct me?

Comment: Method 2 is a little shorter w/o losing any clarity.

Comment: please see the updated question @ScottHunter

Comment: What do you mean by "lost in memory"? Both will have the same scope, go out of scope and be collected the same - **if** you don't pass `getDetailsReq` somewhere else.

Comment: BTW: Class names _should_ start with a capital letter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#pascal-case

Comment: _"which is recommended"_ - I don't know of any specific official recommendation regarding this.

Comment: It actually boils down to the same lowered and optimized code: https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjQG4CGATogC4CmAzi4gLyIB2bAO6IA8gFd2jVABt6HDqUEiAkv0HS5CiuQDc1HAF8DiEwmREAchSowadJq04s1G3gOGJXbTfMV6TB2Z2LndlMUkfWT9SEJd1HwC7XGMYVNhzFAkpaIVYLGScc29fBS8E5gxEAHM2Fl1EVJozJGyorUVyjVyORABLCsRyEwL7XBYACz6OADoS9wGNfULG2HS4fDAu9r98wyA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent if the reference is not use again by the caller. It's very possible the optimizer will remove the temporary variable anyway if it is not used by the calling scope.

> The second one will go untraceable and will be lost somewhere in memory

Well, you pass it to `getTransactionDetailsController`, so presumably *it* does something with the reference. Once the garbage collector detects that no objects have a reference to the object, it will be garbage collected (not disposed).

So use whichever one you feel is better - there is no practical guidance that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise? Nothing.

Readability-wise? I'd argue that the first one is more readable and maintainable than the second one:

- You can set a breakpoint on the appropriate constructor when debugging.
- You can easily inspect / watch the values of `getDetailsReq`.

Comment: please see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you need `getDetailsReq` somewhere else in your code, use method 1. Otherwise, it shouldn't make a difference

Comment: please see the updated question